# Sort objects in array based on two values alphabetically

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, key-value

I have a table which can be sorted on certain values. Currently it is sorted on specific equipmentStatus (not alphabetically, but defined in the initialStatusSorting variable below). However I also need to sort the item name alphabetically if they have the same equipmentStatus value. I give an example what I have now, as you see I want the `name` to be sorted when the `equipmentStatus` is the same

```
[
   {
    equipmentStatus: "available",
    name: "ab pump"
   },
   {
    equipmentStatus: "available",
    name: "aa pump"
   },
   {
    equipmentStatus: "available",
    name: "zbe pump"
   },
   {
    equipmentStatus: "allocated",
    name: "tr pump"
   },
   {
    equipmentStatus: "allocated",
    name: "vx pump"
   },
   {
    equipmentStatus: "allocated",
    name: "re pump"
   },
   {
    equipmentStatus: "RequestMaintenance",
    name: "tt pump"
   },
   {
    equipmentStatus: "RequestMaintenance",
    name: "vd pump"
   },
   {
    equipmentStatus: "RequestMaintenance",
    name: "ph pump"
   },
]
```

Now I have the following function to sort the equipmentStatus based on my given specifications, however I need to still alphabetically order the objects with the same equipmentStatus on the `name` key.

````
    const initialStatusSorting = { "Available" : 1, "Allocated": 2, "RequestMaintenance": 3, "RequestRepair": 4 , "Pickup": 5, default: Infinity };
    this.fetchOverviewPumps(requiredIds).then(() => {
      this.overviewPumps.allPumps.sort(function (a, b) {
        return (initialStatusSorting[a.equipmentStatus] || initialStatusSorting.default) - (initialStatusSorting[b.equipmentStatus] || initialStatusSorting.default) || a.equipmentStatus.localeCompare(b.equipmentStatus);
      });
    })```
````

So to recap: I need to sort 2 key-values, the one on specific equipmentStatus already works with the sort functionality above but I can't get the additional alpabetical sorting working on objects with the same `equipmentStatus` value.

What do I need to add to my existing function to achieve that?

Thanks for helping!

,Coen

Comment: `a.equipmentStatus.localeCompare(b.equipmentStatus)` looks like a typo. You mean `a.name.localeCompare(b.name)`, right? Then, you’re matching `Available`, `Allocated`, etc., but your objects have `available` and `allocated`; that’s inconsistent, and as a result, the objects won’t be sorted correctly. Voting to close as off-topic because the problem is essentially caused by two typos.

Answer (score 1):

To also sort it according to the name alphabetically if the equipmentStatus is the same, you just need to change this line in your code:

```
return (initialStatusSorting[a.equipmentStatus] || initialStatusSorting.default) - (initialStatusSorting[b.equipmentStatus] || initialStatusSorting.default) || a.equipmentStatus.localeCompare(b.equipmentStatus);
```

To this:

```
if (a.equipmentStatus !== b.equipmentStatus)
  return (initialStatusSorting[a.equipmentStatus] || initialStatusSorting.default) - (initialStatusSorting[b.equipmentStatus] || initialStatusSorting.default) || a.equipmentStatus.localeCompare(b.equipmentStatus);
else
  return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
```